flutter : use svg for persistent navbar items
List
<PersistentBottomNavBarItem> _navbarItems = [
    PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
      icon: SvgPicture.asset(
        'images/sofa_home.svg',
        width: 22,
      ),
      activeColorPrimary: ColorsConst.yellow,
      title: 'Home',
      inactiveColorPrimary: ColorsConst.blueThree,
    ),
    PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: SvgPicture.asset(
          'images/sofa_search.svg',
          width: 22,
        ),
        activeColorPrimary: ColorsConst.yellow,
        inactiveColorPrimary: ColorsConst.blueThree,
        title: 'Browse'),
    PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: SvgPicture.asset(
          'images/sofa_profile.svg',
          width: 22,
        ),
        activeColorPrimary: ColorsConst.yellow,
        inactiveColorPrimary: ColorsConst.blueThree,
        title: 'Account'),
  ];

the svg pictures takes as colors their default color , the active and inactive color doesn't affect the svg pictures

You can check this closed issue: https://github.com/BilalShahid13/PersistentBottomNavBar/issues/62 It is answered as 'You'll have to convert your SVG to icon file (ttf) and then import and use in the project.' to make use of your SVGs.
